# Enabling High Velocity Sales in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm trying to set up CI/CD in a project which has "High velocity Sales" enabled as a feature.

The setting file in prod for this feature as it is:

```
<HighVelocitySalesSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableACAutoSendEmail>true</enableACAutoSendEmail>
    <enableACSkipWeekends>true</enableACSkipWeekends>
    <enableDispositionCategory>true</enableDispositionCategory>
    <enableEngagementWaveAnalyticsPref>true</enableEngagementWaveAnalyticsPref>
    <enableHighVelocitySales>true</enableHighVelocitySales>
    <enableHighVelocitySalesSetup>true</enableHighVelocitySalesSetup>
</HighVelocitySalesSettings>
```

If I intent to deploy this setting to the created scratch org, it gives me an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1252004475-310294 (1965024638)
```

Accordingly to the documentation, High velocity Sales is available in scratch orgs, but it can't be updated trough it's setting file:

`High Velocity Sales can be deployed in scratch orgs, but the settings for the feature can’t be updated through the scratch org definition file. Instead, configure settings directly in the High Velocity Sales app.`

So, the only way to enabling this feature in a scratch org is manually?

Comment: Yup. And it feels like we've been here before: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300816/how-do-you-handle-deployment-of-changes-unsupported-in-metadata-api